# Run cmd command as admin through the pipe

Tags: windows-command-prompt, uninstall, administrative-privileges

I find myself in a bit of a weird situation and I'm hoping someone would be able to advise for me.

I have a tool, RMM datto, which allows myself to run commands to all machines on the domain. I'm looking to run an uninstaller on the device, this code works fine. The concern I have is that when I run the command it'll prompt for admin details to execute.

I want to run this command and uninstall the application, however, I don't want to give 500 users a prompt which'll likely freak people out.

My question: Is there a way to "pipe" admin credentials to silently run an application with admin details?

If it matters, the application I'm removing is a Citrix receiver which can be uninstalled running an .exe file.

Comment: `The concern I have is that when I run the command it'll prompt for admin details to execute.` Did you run the command and it prompted for credentials?

Comment: @GregAskew yes, when I manually put the details in it'll run fine and uninstall as expected - I just want to avoid the user seeing any prompt

Comment: You ran the command against a remote computer, and the logged on user of the remote computer received a prompt?

Comment: @GregAskew I've tested this manually on one machine, when running it did prompt - I want to run through a remote tool and imagine everyone else will be prompted with the same code.

Comment: `imagine everyone else will be prompted with the same code`. That needs to be validated.  These types of management tools usually do not require elevation.

Comment: @GregAskew There reason for the prompt is because it's making a change to the system, this makes sense and is expected. I'm not trying to avoid the prompt, i'm simply trying to complete the prompt through the command without having the user involved if that makes sense?

Comment: It doesn't make sense. The UAC prompt is for interactive sessions. If you are running this against a remote system, that is not an interactive session. There are at least three other ways to do this, WMI Process Create, WINRS, and PSEXEC, all of which can do this without any prompting or elevation. As I previously stated, you need to test and validate this.